# Cambiar el contenido de un div y activarlo o desactivarlo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, div

Tengo un `div` en *HTML* con un `select` y quiero que al llamar a una función de *JavaScript* el contenido de este `div` cambie, tras hacer varias cosas en mi código *JavaScript*. Quiero que desaparezca este `select` y aparezca una tabla que rellenaré mediante *JavaScript* para cambiar el contenido.

¿Puedo tener de alguna manera un `div` oculto con la tabla hasta **desactivar** el `div` con el `select` y **activar** el `div` con la tabla?

Sería cambiar el contenido del `div` con `id=loggedin` (la tabla que está en ese `div` no es la que quiero rellenar, esa la utilizo para colocar el `select`).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="loggedin">
 <div id="header">
  Logged in to as <span id="fullName"></span> 
  <a id="disconnect" href="#">Log Out</a>
 </div>
 <div id="output"> </div>
 <table id=tabla style="width:100%">
  <tr> </tr> <tr> <th> </th> </tr>  
  <tr> </tr> <tr> <th> </th> </tr>
  <tr>  
   <th>
    <select class="select" id="boards"></select>
   </th>   
  </tr>
 </table> 
 <span id="res"> nada</span>
 <span id="res2"> nada</span>
 <span id="res3"> nada</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, he puesto el HTML que llevo, aun no tengo el div por el que quiero que cambie, ya que no tenia muy claro si podía "ocultar" ese y mostrar otro div o tendría que cambiar el contenido desde Javascript,

Comment: Las dos opciones son válidas: puedes tener previamente los dos div e ir mostrando el que quieras o puedes reemplazar el HTML. Si el contenido es estático veo más sencillo tener los dos, si el contenido del segundo es dinámico quizá sea más fácil generarlo

Comment: Mi idea era no cambiar el HTML completo, solo el div, ya que me facilitaría las cosas bastante por el código que ya tengo creado, pero no se cómo se puede "mostrarse" y "ocultarse un div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se suele manejar el estilo del `DOM` con `CSS`, en tu caso que quieres ocultar una `div` puedes hacerlo con:

```html
<div id="none" style="display:none">div oculta con style="display:none"</div>
<div id="hide" style="visibility:hidden">div oculta con style="visibility:hidden"</div>
```

Para mostrar una `div` que está oculta lo puedes hacer con **javascript**:

```js
function visible() {
 document.getElementById("none").style.display="";
 document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility="";
}
```

```html
<div id="none" style="display:none">div oculta con style="display:none"</div>
<div id="hide" style="visibility:hidden">div oculta con style="visibility:hidden"</div>
<button onclick="visible()">Hacer visible</button>
```

Para ocultar una `div` que está visible lo puedes hacer con **javascript**:

```js
function ocultar() {
 document.getElementById("none").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

```html
<div id="none">puede ocultar con style="display:none"</div>
<div id="hide">o tambien con style="visibility:hidden"</div>
<button onclick="ocultar()">ocultar</button>
```

Para cambiar el contenido de una `div` puede hacerlo con la propiedad del **DOM**: `innerHTML`

```js
function cambiar() {
 document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML= "Como estas? ;))...";
}
```

```html
<div id="MyDiv">Hola Mundo!!</div>
<button onclick="cambiar()">Cambiar el Contenido de una DIV</button>
```

Espero esto aclare tus dudas ;))...

Comment: Me fue muy útil, gracias por tu explicación tan detallada :)

Answer (score 1):

Para que un div cambie dinamicamente por javascript tenes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("loggedin").html = "" //modifica todo el contenido dentro del div
document.getElementById("loggedin").html += "" //añade contenido dentro del div
```